# Create Multiple Instances Of Same Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently building a website that uses windows to load in new content via ajax. These windows are allowed to contain the same page as in another window using the same javascript. Currently I assign a unique id to the new window which it then stores for later use.

Once the code is loaded in, all the ids in that window are converted by adding on to them a unique_id. ie "box" becomes "box_win1". I then send this id to the javascript by assigning it to a variable so it can be used in document.ready function.

The pseudo code for the window is like the following:

```
 document.ready{
var temp_id=id+1;
        $("#mybox" + temp_id).val("abc")
    //run some startup stuff
    }
```

I am just wondering is there a better way to do this. As I find if I open to many new windows all at once the temp_id conflicts and goes to the wrong window.

I would like to some how create an instance of the code but I am not sure how. I cannot use global functions however as that may cause naming conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

put this into a function

```
function callMe (){

    var temp_id=id+1;
        $("#mybox" + temp_id).val("abc")
    //run some startup stuff


}
```

you can use callMe() anywhere then

Comment: Isn't that just creating a global function though?